# Function to calculate the first partial derivative of another function using Maxima

Tags: maxima

I want to write a function, `mydiff`, that has a single argument, a 2-arg function, and computes the partial derivative w.r.t. to the first argument.  Something like:

```
mydiff(f) := lambda([x, y], diff(f(x, y), x))
```

But, `diff` needs to be run when `mydiff` is called, not when it's defined (we don't have the definition of `f` at that point), or when `lambda` body is being executed (`x` may have been replaced by a constant or complex expression at that point).

Specifically, how can I fill in the definition of `mydiff` below?

```
mydiff(f) := ...;

myf(a, b) := a^2*b;

mydiff(myf)(3, 7);
```

Gives the answer `2*3*7` = `42`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this.

```
mydiff (f) :=
  block ([defn, vars, body], 
         defn: apply (fundef, [f]), 
         vars: args (lhs (defn)), 
         body: rhs (defn), 
         makelist (diff (body, vv), vv, vars), 
         apply (lambda, [vars, %%]));
```

`fundef` retrieves the function definition like `f(x) := ...`. Get the list of variables as the arguments of the left-hand side of the definition (i.e., `f(x)` for example) and the body as the right-hand side (i.e., the `...` stuff). Make a list by differentiating the body wrt each variable. Finally, package the result as a `lambda` expression which takes the same variables as arguments. Note that `%%` is the preceding value in a sequence of expressions (i.e. in `block` or `(...)`).

You'll note the use of `apply` to ensure that arguments are evaluated for `fundef` and `lambda`. In the interest of brevity I'll omit the explanation for now.

Here's what I get with that definition.

```
(%i44) myf(a, b) := a^2*b;
                                      2
(%o44)                  myf(a, b) := a  b
(%i45) mydiff(myf);
                                           2
(%o45)             lambda([a, b], [2 a b, a ])
(%i46) mydiff(myf)(3, 7);
(%o46)                       [42, 9]
```